# Update LinearLayout based on response

Tags: android, json, android-layout, retrofit2

What I am trying to do is based on the response I get from JSON using Retrofit, to update a linearlayout on the bottom of my mainActivity.

I know I can hide/unhide items, but is it possible to save a linearlayout? For example there are two types of linearlayouts(one with text and image, the other with text and two images that are places around the horizontal layout differently). Now if the JSON response returns objects that are null, I want to then use linearlayout-1. If I get a different response that fits my requirements for linearlayout-2, then use that one.

Comment: try to create dynamic layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solutions would be to have two layouts at bottom, and show and hide them depending on response.

Comment: by using `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ` to make visible, or `setVisibility(View.GONE) ` to make invisible and doesn't take the space

Comment: So essentially have layouts on top of each other and just control the visibility programmatically based on the response?

Comment: Yes. If layout visibility is gone it will not be drawn.